# Creating one generic scrapy spider and multiple specific

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to create one generic spider which takes care of the most common tasks and specific spiders which inherit the generic one and declare website specific variables.

There is the `genericspider.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider, CrawlSpider

class GenericProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, start_urls=[], finditemprop='', keywords='', **kwargs):
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        print ( "\n\n Init Generic \n" )
```

And then I've got the `specificspider.py` in the same directory as the generic one.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider, CrawlSpider
from .genericfabric import GenericFabricsSpider

class SpecificSpider(GenericProductSpider):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print ( "\n init specific \n" )
        name = "specific1"
        start_urls = ['http://www.specificdomian.com',]

        super(SpecificSpider, self).__init__(name, start_urls, **kwargs)
```

I seem to have understanding issues on how to properly call the initializer of the superclass. I get all sorts of error messages but the **init** method of the generic spider has never been executed.

Comment: Look up cookiecutter python module the look up cookiecutter scrapy templates.... y

Comment: @scriptso that looks interesting. As far as I understand it, that would be kind of a template and I could throw my variables inside and it creates the spiders for me? In case I need to update code though, I need to update it in all the spiders I assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually .. it seems to be working fine - there were probably just issues with the parameters.

Working code for the super class:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from test.items import TestItem


class TestsuperSpider(Spider):
    name = "testsuper"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo"]
    supervar = "meine super var"

    def __init__(self):
        print ( "super init" )

    def parse(self, response):
        print ( "super Parse" )

    def supermethod ( self, subvar ):
        print ( "\n\n Supermethod \n\n " )
        print ( self.supervar + " - " + subvar )
```

And the subclass:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from test.items import TestItem
from test.spiders.testsuper import TestsuperSpider


class TestsubSpider(TestsuperSpider):
    name = "testsub"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo"]
    subvar = "subvar"

    def __init__(self):
        print ( "sub init" )
        super(TestsubSpider, self).__init__()

    def parse(self, response):
        super(TestsubSpider, self).supermethod(self.subvar)
        print ( "sub Parse" )
```

Now it needs cleaning up and adjusting it to it's purpose, but at least the code runs as expected.